# App says Image Downloaded Successfully but no image shows up in gallery

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The app gets the image from the given URL and displays the image and on clicking the download button, it says that the image has been downloaded successfully but there is no image in the gallery. Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

This is my Image View and Download activity. I have also added proper permissions to the Android Manifest.

```
private Button btnImageDownload;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private ImageView viewDownloadImage;
private Images imageId;
private File folderName;
private String imageName;

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            Utils.showNetworkAlert(ImageViewAndDownload.this);
        } else if (msg.what == 2) {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            Utils.displayMessage("Image downloade succesfully",
                    ImageViewAndDownload.this);
            // Media scaning
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); 
        } else if (msg.what == 3) {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            Utils.displayMessage("Image already downloaded ",
                    ImageViewAndDownload.this);
        } else if (msg.what == 4) {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            displayImageFromUrl((Bitmap) msg.obj);
        }

    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagedisplay);

    viewDownloadImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
    btnImageDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImageDownload);
    imageId = new Images();
    imageName = imageId.getImageId();
    LoadImageFromWeb(Constant.IMAGE_BASE_URL + File.separator + imageName);
    btnImageDownload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnImageDownload) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(ImageViewAndDownload.this, "",
                "Downloading Image....", true, false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    String imageUrl = Constant.IMAGE_BASE_URL
                            + File.separator + imageName;
                    String isDownloded = downloadImage(imageUrl, imageName);
                    if (isDownloded.equalsIgnoreCase("complete")) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                    } else if (isDownloded.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
                    } else {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
}

// set display image to Imageview
public void displayImageFromUrl(Bitmap obj) {
    viewDownloadImage.setImageBitmap(obj);
}

// image display from the webview
private void LoadImageFromWeb(final String url1) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(ImageViewAndDownload.this, "",
            "Loading Image....", true, false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(url1);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

                Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

                if (options.outWidth > 3000 || options.outHeight > 2000) {
                    options.inSampleSize = 4;
                } else if (options.outWidth > 2000
                        || options.outHeight > 1500) {
                    options.inSampleSize = 3;
                } else if (options.outWidth > 1000
                        || options.outHeight > 1000) {
                    options.inSampleSize = 2;
                }
                // Do the actual decoding
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                is.close();
                is = getHTTPConnectionInputStream(url1);
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null,
                        options);
                is.close();

                if (myBitmap != null) {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = myBitmap;
                    msg.what = 4;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                } else {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public InputStream getHTTPConnectionInputStream(String url1) {
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(url1);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        is = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return is;
}

// image download code
public String downloadImage(String imageDownloadUrl, String imageName) {
    // create directory in SDCARD
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        folderName = new File(Constant.STORE_IN_FOLDER);
    else
        folderName = getFilesDir();

    if (!folderName.exists())
        folderName.mkdirs();

    String response = "";
    // create file name and file.
    File storeImageInSDCard = new File(folderName + File.separator
            + imageName);
    if (!(storeImageInSDCard.exists() && storeImageInSDCard.length() > 0)) {
        // start download image
        response = downloadFile(imageDownloadUrl, imageName,
                folderName.toString());
    }
    return response;
}

// start download image
public String downloadFile(final String url, final String name,
        String foldername) {

    File file;
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    try {

        URL url1 = new URL(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
        System.out.println("Image url :::" + url1);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1
                .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // here create a file which define folder name and image name with
        // extension.
        file = new File(foldername, name + ".jpg");
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();

        // if image size is too large we can scale image than download.
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory
                .decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        if (options.outWidth > 3000 || options.outHeight > 2000) {
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
        } else if (options.outWidth > 2000 || options.outHeight > 1500) {
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
        } else if (options.outWidth > 1000 || options.outHeight > 1000) {
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory
                .decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        myBitmap.recycle();

        return "complete";
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you expect the image to be available in the gallery?

Comment: That's what I want the code to do, is it wrong? I want the application to download that image and store it in the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

try this, 
After saving the Image you have to use this

```
 Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
 Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
 mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
 getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

you have to send a broadcast to System ,changes to reflect in the `Gallery` , so that you image will be shown in the gallery , if not , you have to restart Device for check the downloaded images..

hope it helps you..

Comment: The image does not appear in the gallery even after restarting the device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use **Aquery** for image download it is very Useful for image download from net.

[Here the link](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) for Aquery